# Menu-bar disappears when on mobile version

Tags: media-queries, minimize

When I refresh my website on the phone my responsive design (menu bar) is not working. Not working like disappears... It's just gone.
Only menu bar.

So here is my media query code:

```
@media all and (max-width: 800px), 
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px),
only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px),
only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1) and (max-width: 1024px),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px),
only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi) and (max-width: 1024px),
only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  #cssmenu {
    background: black;
  }
}
```

Maybe I should add JavaScript? 
Help!!

Comment: That is the most intense media-query I've ever seen. You're missing a closing `}` at the very end.

Comment: Yes yes I have that... I just didn't write whole css code...
How you mean intense?

Anything else why it's not working?
I was thinking that maybe some other code like js, messed up this... Is that possible?

Comment: Trying removing (or turn off in the browser) your JS to rule that out. It would help if you would post the corresponding html markup. And to help troubleshoot, it's a good idea to reduce your media-query to just the basics (remove vendor prefixes and logical operators and just use the max-width property)

Comment: Tried... Nothing happens still. So JS is not the problem...
Here is html:

"<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li class='active'><a href='#'><span>Home</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>Products</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>Company</span></a></li>
   <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>"

I guess I shouldn't write ID's in selectors but that's still not a problem.
And I've reduced the media query to the minimum....

Comment: I've recreated your code here: https://jsfiddle.net/lewisrodgers/2rrenvtL/1/ . Resize the results panel... Is it how you expect things to work?

Comment: Can you see it now https://jsfiddle.net/2rrenvtL/11/ ? I updated it with all my styles.

Answer (score 0):

It's the display none on line 224 in your css code. Remove it and you should be good.

```
#cssmenu > ul {
    display: none;
}
```